# How do I configure cross-origin with @import url()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I need to include a style with a URL, but i need to change the cross-origin, like you would in a script.

I've tried looking around different mdn web docs, such as @import, url(), and cross-origin, couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's just a GET request, you configure it as any HTTP request on the server

Comment: What about [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)? There's [`crossorigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) there: *The `crossorigin` attribute, valid on the `<audio>`, `<img>`, **`<link>`**, `<script>`, and `<video>` elements, provides support for CORS.*